# AlarmManager with pending intents to update a widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, alarmmanager

I have a requirement where in i need to updated my widget once in every 15 seconds. There is a method called `android:updatePeriodMillis` but that seems to be getting fired only after 30 minutes.

I took an approach of *updating my Widget* with the help of `AlarmManager`. The *widget updates* but the issue is it slows down the performance of the device. When the `AlarmManager` of my application runs on the background i could see a big delay on the device to respond to user events. **Is it wise to have a widget that updates frequently?**

**Is it the recommended approach to update the widget**..or can any one provide me some code samples or any application where the update happens frequently?.

**Why is that the `android:updatePeriodMillis` is set to 30 mins?. Is it because Android does not want us to update a widget before that time interval?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a requirement where in i need to updated my widget once in every 15 seconds.

That is going to have repercussions for your battery life. Please make this configurable.

> There is a method called android:updatePeriodMillis but that seems to be getting fired only after 30
>   minutes.

It is an XML attribute, not a method, and yes, it has a 30-minute minimum, because of complaints regarding battery life from users who install app widgets that update, say, every 15 seconds.

> When the AlarmManager of my application runs on the background i could see a big delay on the device to
>   respond to user events.

Put your time-consuming work in an `IntentService`, triggered by the alarm. If you are doing your work directly in a `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive()` method, that runs at foreground priority and will have a greater impact on CPU usage. Also, it ties up the main application thread of your process, and so any activities you have running will be stuck while the `BroadcastReceiver` does its work.

> Is it wise to have a widget that updates frequently?

IMHO, no, but if you make it configurable, then the user can choose what value they feel is appropriate.